# How to create a derived type of a native (node.js) class/constructor?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, inheritance, node-modules

I have a native node.js module that exports a constructor function which uses `ObjectWrap`. It uses the Nan module and roughly looks like this:

```
// Create scope
NanScope();

// Initialize wrapper
auto *mw = new MyWrap();
...

// Wrap the this object
mw->Wrap(args.This());

NanReturnThis();
```

I'd like to inherit from this constructor. Here's what I've tried:

```
var m = require('myModule');
function Derived () { }
util.inherits(Derived, m.MyConstructor);
```

After that:

```
var d = new Derived();
```

The result is that `d instanceof m.MyConstructor` returns `true`, but if I pass a `Derived` instance to native functions that accept an instance of `m.MyConstructor`, they cannot unwrap it because its `InternalFieldCount()` is `0`.

Also tried the following:

```
function Derived () { m.MyConstructor.call(this); }
```

Which resulted in a similar problem:

```
void node::ObjectWrap::Wrap(v8::Handle<v8::Object>): Assertion `handle->InternalFieldCount() > 0' failed.`
```

What's the right way to inherit from a constructor function that uses `ObjectWrap` under the hood?

Comment: javascript does not support extending native classes